# Como fazer um loop infinito de contagem em Java?

Tags: java, loop, while

Estou iniciando meus estudos com Java agora e gostaria de saber como fazer uma contagem infinita estou com dificuldades, pois sei que em Python seria algo do tipo:

```
a = 0
while True:
    a = a + 1
    print(a)
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer em Java? Como ficou? Deu algum erro?

Comment: Mas qual é a utilidade deste loop assim como está ? Ou é para tentar perceber loops ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seja qual for a linguagem, seu "infinito" é relativo ao tamanho máximo que o tipo de dado que você for utilizar suporta ou, em último caso, a memória disponível de sua máquina. Isso quer dizer que infinito de um `Integer` é bem (BEM) menor que o infinito de um `BigInteger`, por exemplo. Em outras palavras, infinito já é por si um engano conceitual.

Isso posto, uma forma de *loop* "infinito", o maior que você conseguirá em Java até lotar a memória do seu equipamento:

```
BigInteger infinito = BigInteger.ZERO;
for(;;) {
   infinito = infinito.add(BigInteger.ONE);
   System.out.println(infinito);
}
```

Comment: Será que chega a lotar a memória? Porque os números não estão sendo guardados (se vc estivesse adicionando em uma `List`, por exemplo, aí lotaria mesmo), vc só imprime e depois descarta, então acho que o GC consegue segurar as pontas. Talvez o maior impacto seja a CPU, por causa de todo o I/O feito para imprimir todos os números: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585337

Comment: Creio que chega a lotar sim, pelo que se infere da doc.: _All of the details in the Spec concerning overflow are ignored, as BigIntegers are made as large as necessary to accommodate the results of an operation._, [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: É verdade, eu estava pensando em `int`, mas com `BigInteger` de fato vai lotar

Answer (score 0):

Baseando-se na resposta do StatelessDev, que levantou a ideia de uma contagem (em teoria) infinita.
Poderíamos simplificar/deixar o código mais legível e transaprente tirando o for(;;) e deixando-o com um while(true):

```
BigInteger contagem = BigInteger.ZERO;
while(true) {
   contagem = contagem.add(BigInteger.ONE);
   System.out.println(contagem);
}
```